# How to see the code generated by the compiler

Tags: c++, testing, compiler-construction

Guys in one of excersises (ch.5,e.8) from TC++PL Bjarne asks to do following:
  '"Run some tests to see if your compiler really generates equivalent code for iteration using pointers and iteration using indexing. If different degrees of optimization can be requested, see if and how that affects the quality of the generated code"'

Any idea how to eat it and with what?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: How you examine the generated code depends on your compiler. There's probably a compiler option to output generated assembly, or you could use a tool like `objdump`, or a debugger with assembly view. You very much want any options to interleave source and (dis)assembly. If you don't understand asm code (x86 or x64, most likely), then it's a tricky exercise: I guess if the output is identical you can verify that without understanding a single byte of it, otherwise it's going to be hard to assess "equivalence" or especially "quality".

Comment: You should try phrasing the title as a question that says something about what you're after. "In Bjarne's book." does neither.

Comment: @atch Gave your question a relevant title. As @Marcus says, please write titles that actually tell us something about your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to write code something like this:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
int n = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
   n += a[i];
}

int * p = a;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
   n += *p++;
}
```

Then you need to compile it with compiler options that gets your compiler to emit assembly language, and take  a look at it. It's also instructive to do this both with and without optimisations turned on.

Answer (score 3):

```
int sum_with_array_indexing(int* p, int size)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        s += p[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int sum_with_pointer_arithmetic(int* p, int size)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        s += *p++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

`g++ -S -O2` yields identical code:

```
__Z23sum_with_array_indexingPii:
LFB0:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI0:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI1:
    pushl   %ebx
LCFI2:
    movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    jle L8
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 2,,3
L4:
    addl    (%ebx,%edx,4), %eax
    incl    %edx
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx
    jne L4
L3:
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    ret
L8:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp L3
```

and:

```
__Z27sum_with_pointer_arithmeticPii:
LFB1:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI3:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI4:
    pushl   %ebx
LCFI5:
    movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    jle L15
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    .p2align 2,,3
L12:
    addl    (%ebx,%edx,4), %eax
    incl    %edx
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx
    jne L12
L11:
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    ret
L15:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp L11
```